# gnuplot with iOS

Tags: ios, gnuplot

Does anyone here have experiences of using gnuplot with iOS? I want to develop a scientific computing app on iOS devices and want to use gnuplot as the plotting engine. Are there any good tutorials from which I can start with?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same general question, a quick google search led me to the following app, which seems to use gnuplot.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/icas-workstation-class-scientific/id394637176

I followed the trail to their website:

http://alsoftiphone.com/iCAS/

I contacted them about it, and I will follow up if/when I get a response.

---

**The response:**

Hello,

As you've aptly pointed out, there are some complications when embedding gnuplot in an app, particularly if you intend to dynamically create and dispose of it.  That is, gnuplot (as of v4.4.0 which is what I used) doesn't explicitly release some memory that it allocates presumably because it assumes that it will be released when it is quit, which would be the case when it is used as a standalone application.  This will of course result in memory leaks.  Similarly, gnuplot doesn't explicitly close its output file descriptor (which is set to `stdout` as far as I know).  And it also doesn't clear multiplot mode when the main function exits which is problematic because the next time you call gnuplot in an embedded situation, some global variables will reflect multiplot mode if called thereafter.

Fortunately for you, I've already identified them so you won't have to hunt them down like I did.  Unfortunately, though, I didn't create a library for my projects but here are the relevant changes that you'll need to make to the gnuplot source code.

`plot.c` line #615, at the end of the else block for the `"if (interactive && term != 0)"` conditional block of the `main()` function (which you will also want to change to some appropriate entry function name):

```cpp
// Free replot_line
if (replot_line != NULL)
{
    free(replot_line);
    replot_line = NULL;
}
```

`plot.c` line #680, before "return exit_status" at the end of the `main()` function:

```cpp
// Free replot_line if it was allocated
if (replot_line != NULL)
    free(replot_line);

// Clear multiplot mode, if it was active
if (multiplot)
    term_end_multiplot();

// Close current file
if (gpoutfile)
    fclose(gpoutfile);
```

The other issue is that gnuplot is written to use stdin and stdout so for my apps I replaced them with my own appropriate file descriptors to serve as the interface to/from gnuplot. That will be implementation specific, so I won't list my own particular changes but you'll basically need to look through the gnuplot source for instances of stdin and stdout and replace them as appropriate for your needs.

You'll also want to `#define NO_GIH` in `config.h`.

Other than that, you'll probably need to hard code the appropriate gnuplot terminal type for your app (I used SVG in my apps).

I hope this helps.

Best Regards,

Antonio Lagana